# Alternative to using Zxing in app inventor

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, app-inventor

I have been using Zxing barcode scanner which has been working well but not great however I have found a better performing external scanner called scandit but whenever I want to scan in my app it says that I do not have a scanner installed whereas with Zxing it instantly launched, scanned and presented the outcome in a textbox.

I have used App Inventor to create my app which is scanning bar-codes using an external scanner and then posting the results to an online spreadsheet on the click of a submit button.

Can someone please help me make my app able to use a different scanner moving on  from the Zxing one preferably the scandit one in my app.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the [documentation](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/sensors.html#BarcodeScanner), for the built-in barcode scanner there are 2 options (true or false) you can set in the `UseExternalScanner` property

> UseExternalScanner
>       If true App Inventor will look for and use an external scanning program such as "Bar Code Scanner."

If setting `UseExternalScanner` to true does not work together with that other scanner app, then there is not much you can do. The only thing you can try is to use that scanner via the `activity starter` component, [see here for more information](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/activitystarter.html).

Alternatively set `UseExternalScanner` to false and try the built-in scanner functionality.